# VisualForce prevent double clicking on a button

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

I have done a lot of research on this, and can not figure out the best way to solve this. I am trying to prevent a user from clicking multiple times on a custom button in a VF page. When that is done, they invoke the method related to the button multiple times. I saw quite a few posts with different solutions, but most of them are on posts from 5-10 years ago.

Comment: Check mine? https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/194195/799 only 1.5 years old ;)

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I do like your solution a lot, but settled for this one : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/7729/disable-commandbutton-after-first-click-to-prevent-double-submission

Comment: Cool one too. I like mine because while you have to duplicate some buttons - you don't write any JavaScript. If you want - post your own solution as answer here so it future searches have something that'll help them!

Answer (score 1):

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
<script>

    function buttonsEnabled(enabled) {
        // retrieve all of the buttons or links on the page
        // with the css class of btn
        var $buttons = jQuery('.btn');
        if (enabled === false) {
            // add the btnDisabled class to give it the look of being disabled
            // add the disabled attribute to actually disable interactability
            $buttons.toggleClass('btnDisabled', true).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            // remove the css class and the disabled attribute
            $buttons.toggleClass('btnDisabled', false).attr('disabled', null);
        } 
    }

    function doSomeWork() {
        // first, call the action function to post the form
        doSomeWorkActionFunction();

        // second, disable the buttons
        buttonsEnabled(false);

        // third, return false to prevent the click from
        // posting the form a second time
        return false;
    }

</script>

<apex:form>

    <apex:actionFunction name="doSomeWorkActionFunction" 
        action="{!yourControllerMethod}" 
        oncomplete="buttonsEnabled(true);"
        rerender="whateverYouNeedToRerender"></apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:commandLink action="{!yourControllerMethod}" 
        value="Your Text Here" 
        id="theCommandLink" 
        onclick="return doSomeWork();" />

</apex:form>
```